# Is it possible to climb Mt. Fuji in November?

Tags: japan, mount-fuji

I understand this is outside of the climbing season. It appears to be legal and the risks are higher, but I'd like to know if it's even really possible or is snow usually too deep at this time and temperatures too low to even consider it. I climbed Mt. Kilimanjaro last year so I have a good idea of what these treks are about. Do any guides operate in November?

Comment: I saw that question but it doesn't answer my question. In the upvoted answer the fuji guides site stops tours in September... hence I still don't know if it's possible to go in November.